# Como exibir partes de uma pagina apenas após o carregamento de todo o conteúdo do site?

Tags: javascript

Queria saber como fazer um JS, para exibir o conteúdo de determinadas partes de um site, apenas após todo o conteudo ter sido carregado, isso inclui, JS, Imagens, CSS e Alguns dados externos como o retorno do plugin do facebook...

Está resolvido combinando as resposta de 
thiagobarradas e Silvio Andorinha

E mesmo não sendo totalmente eficas, como os dados do facebook são os primeiros a serem chamados da tempo de carregar tudo ja que os dados posteriores a ele são mais lentos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o **DEFER**

### HTML

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display: none;">
  <!-- qualquer coisa aqui -->
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" DEFER="DEFER">

 document.getElementById("hiddenDiv").style.display = "block";

</script>
```

**NOTA:** O DEFER indica que o bloco script só será carregado após todo o carregamento da página.

para mais detalhes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: @RodrigoBorth olha essa.

Comment: Tente utilizar fontes de refência mais confiáveis que o w3schools, aqui tem um [tópico](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/692/w3schools-e-uma-referencia-horrivel-certo) no meta. O [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) fala de alguns problemas do w3schools.

Comment: Ok, vou achar outro site de referencia...

Comment: realmente, nunca havia ouvido falar em DEFER e realmente resolve completamente o problema

Answer (score 4):

Usando HTML, CSS e JS:

```
<!doctype html>     
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Carregar parte após todo carregamento</title>
    <style>
        /* inicia a div 'depois' invisível */
        /* seletor css por id */
        #depois { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script>
        /* função JS 'mostrarConteudo()' que identifica objeto 'depois' e torna-o visível */
        function mostrarConteudo() {
            var elemento = document.getElementById("depois");
            elemento.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>    
</head>
<!-- ao evento 'onload' (carregar a página) acione a função mostrarConteudo() -->
<body onload="mostrarConteudo();">  
    <div id="main">
        <!-- Conteúdo Inicial -->
    </div>
    <div id="depois">
        <!-- Carregar Após Carregamento Inicial -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Utilizando jQuery:

```
<!doctype html>     
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Carregar parte após todo carregamento</title>
    <!-- importa a biblioteca jQuery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <style>
        /* inicia a div 'depois' invisível */
        /* seletor css por id */
        #depois { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script>
        /* .ready é equivalente ao onload. define uma função anônima para mostrar div */
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#depois").css("display", "block");
        });
    </script>    
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="main">
        <!-- Conteúdo Inicial -->
    </div>
    <div id="depois">
        <!-- Carregar Após Carregamento Inicial -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Referências:

> [CSS: display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
>
> [JavaScript: getElementById()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)
>
> [JavaScript: style](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)
>
> [JavaScript: style.display](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)
>
> [JQuery: ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
>
> [JQuery: css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Estou editando, infelizmente por mania usei tab ao invés de 4 espaços e enviei antes mesmo de formular parte da resposta... aguarde.

Comment: Imaginei que fosse um problema de [*Fastest Gun in the West*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) mesmo.

Comment: passando o <script> para o final da pagina funcionou melhor que o onload, já que o mesmo ignora o que está fora da body... pelo menos nos navegadores que testei deu tempo de carregar o conteudo do twitter e do facebook antes de exibir :D

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Se você quer exibir apenas depois que o facebook/twitter terminarem de carregar (não, isso não está claro na pergunta), vai precisar de alguma notificação vinda deles, um callback talvez. Qualquer outro método é apenas uma aproximação e não vai funcionar em todos os cados. Sugiro dar mais detalhes na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode por aquilo que não quer visível em um elemento com `display: none;` e, em um momento oportuno, como no `body.onload`, o tornar visível.

```html
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display: none;">
  <!-- qualquer coisa aqui -->
</div>
```

```js
document.getElementById("hiddenDiv").style.display = "block";
```

Mas se quiser deixar literalmente invisível (ou seja, ocupando espaço no layout), pode trabalhar com a propriedade `opacity` em vez da `display`. Se convier, pode incluir um breve fade ao carregar a página. Fica mais sutil para o usuário final do que ter um elemento surgindo do nada e movendo todos os outros para novas posições.

Comment: o problema disso é que mesmo colocando o onload na body ele carrega antes dos JS

Comment: Você diz, antes do `<script>` carregar e executar o arquivo? Ou antes de alguma função de carregamento de alguma biblioteca (você mencionou um plugin do facebook) retornar? Nesse segundo caso você precisa ver uma forma de ter um callback com a própria biblioteca e executar isso nele.

Comment: ignorando o caso do facebook, ainda assim, ele carrega as imagens e todo o html, mas exibe o conteudo antes dos scripts carregarem completamente, esse scripts estao na head do html

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Tente o `window.onload` em vez do `body.onload`

Comment: Queres JS puro? É que pode ser feito com o jQuery, utilizando o $(document).ready(function(){...}); ou o $(windows).load(function(){...});

Comment: pode ser em jquery tambem

Answer (score -2):

Em css defina:

```
 // Seletor com ID  
 #parte{
     display: none;
 }
```

Em jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Seletor com ID
    $('#parte').css("display", "block");


})
```

Quando o documento for lido(carregado) a `#parte`(qualquer elemento com o `ID="parte"`) deixará de ter um `display: none` (invisivel) e terá um `display: block`(visível)

Comment: e se levar mais de 1 segundo? nao posso deixar a pessoas que tem internet rapida esperando ou a que tem a internet lenta vendo o conteudo todo errado

Comment: diminua, apenas mude para 300 milissegundos ou menos

Comment: Pode explixar melhor a solução?

Comment: A questão é mostrar o conteúdo após o carregamento completo da página, e não mostrar após um tempo definido aleatoriamente.